# Integrating JSON data to highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Lets say I want to use JSON code from one site, particular this one, "http://coinmarketcap.com/static/generated_pages/currencies/datapoints/boostcoin-main.json", to integrate it for my highcharts. As I have seen this has following values: x_min, x_max and price_data. How can I make highcharts on my site using this JSON data? Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example and how it uses JSON code and notice how the JSON data should be, because it changes with every chart type: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/YWVHx/

```
$.getJSON('THE LINK TO YOUR FILE',
function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts(
       ...
       data : data,
       ...
    );
});
```

EDIT: More information about [working with data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing)